# Android - How to disable auto rotation in portrait mode?

Tags: android

I have an activity that always rotates in the 2 view modes(portrait and auto-rotation) but want it to rotate only in auto-rotation mode.
I have set in my manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".Controlling"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

but when I am in portrait mode (when the activity should be fixed), it is still rotating.

I was looking to do it programmatically by using

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

but still does nothing
Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Are you doing programmatically from activity or fragment?

Comment: I do it from a fragment controller, is it related ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change out android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it from fragment then you need to give an activity context.

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
```

Try with this and let me know it works for you or not.

Comment: When I add it to a fragment controller, the screen locks but doesn't rotate in auto mode

Comment: Can you add SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR instead of SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT.